# I can't figure out what rtype is supposed to be

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

In module opencv-python. There is the possibility (not certain) to convert an image format to another using the method: `cv2.cuda_GpuMat.convertTo()`. When reviewing the docstring, I can't tell what `rtype` is supposed to mean:

```
   convertTo(rtype[, dst]) -> dst
    .   



    convertTo(rtype, stream[, dst]) -> dst
    .   



    convertTo(rtype, alpha[, dst[, beta]]) -> dst
    .   



    convertTo(rtype, alpha, stream[, dst]) -> dst
    .   



    convertTo(rtype, alpha, beta, stream[, dst]) -> dst
    .
```

I can only guess that `dst` refers to the destination file. However the usage of this method is such:

```
import cv2

convert = cv2.cuda_GpuMat

image = imread("photo.png")
image.convert.convertTo(rtype, "img.jpg")
```

Comment: Where did you found this usage?

Comment: @zteffi In python cli: import module cv2, then just type `help(cv2.cuda_GpuMat.converTo)`

Comment: I meant the `image.convert.convertTo(rtype, "img.jpg")` line